# osDelay() do not wait enough

Tags: c, arm, stm32, freertos

I write a program for stm32l433 and use freeRTOS in tickless IDLE mode which I changed it to enter STOP mode instead of default SLEEP mode.
When I modify from SLEEP to STOP, osDelay() function works abnormally.For example when its argument is 100 & 1000 there is no difference and it generate same delay.Why it works so?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

FreeRTOS's tick rate means that your OS is going to run at **1kHz** clock. It won't change your `osDelay(...)` delaying values in miliseconds. The difference between 100 and 1000 tick rate is only OS's clock rate, not the delay indicators.

Comment: Are you using SysTick?

Comment: I use sysTick as my RTOS clock and TIM6 as other parts clock

Comment: Did you try to use TIM1 (or any other unused TIMx) as RTOS clock?

Comment: No, as I said I use sysTick as clock for freeRTOS and TIM6 as clock source for other parts.